# Radiobuttons selecting more than one option from value in for loop tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

When selecting a Radiobutton, if two of the options have the same element/value they are both selected.

```
from tkinter import*

class CourseInfo:
    def __init__(self, subject):
        self.subjectName = subject
        self.selectedselected = "0" #default setting

class SubjectGUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        #setting up list for subject objects
        self.subjectInfo = [CourseInfo("English"), CourseInfo("English"), CourseInfo("Math"), CourseInfo("Math")]

        #set up for subject radio buttons
        self.subjectChoice = StringVar() #instance for StringVar created
        self.subjectChoice.set("*") #sets the initial selection

        self.rb_info = []

        for subject in self.subjectInfo: #for loop outputs show info
            self.show_rb = Radiobutton(parent, variable = self.subjectChoice, value = subject.subjectName, text = subject.subjectName, command = self.select_subject)
            self.rb_info.append(self.subjectChoice)
            self.show_rb.pack()

        self.selection_label = Label(text = "You have selected: ")
        self.selection_label.pack()

    def select_subject(self):

        for i in range(len(self.subjectInfo)):
            subject = self.rb_info[i].get()
            self.subjectInfo[i].selectedselected = subject


        self.selection_label.configure(text = "You have selected: " + subject)


# main routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    subjectChoice = SubjectGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I made it so the elements i appended to my list were different (eg CourseInfo("English1"), CourseInfo("English2")...) and my program worked how i wanted it to. It is just when the elements are the same that it does not work. I tried appending to a list as shown above but this did not solve my error.

How do i make it so that only one Radiobutton is selected even if the element/value is the same?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a radiobutton is that each one has a different value. They aren't designed to work with two radiobuttons in a set having the same value.